# How to compute coordinates of rectange and then do perspective transformation using opencv and python

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, hough-transform, canny-operator

[Original pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1n4be.jpg)

[after canny pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ilxhd.jpg)

[pic after perspective tranform](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZXUh.jpg)

Hi,

I am doing a small OCR POC.See the original pic, I only care about the content inside the nameplate.Before recognising characters, I need to do perspective transformation for this pictures to increase correctness. See the second picutures, I already did canny to get the contours of the rectangle.

I want to get the coordinates of the 4 corners of the rectangle(labled in red),so that I can derived the matrix and do perspective transfromation. The last picture is the output I want.

I am new to opencv... can anybody give me some idea regarding how to get the coordinates of 4 corners? I have googled and learn some terms, such as hough transformation? 
Is it a good way to detect line and then computer the position of the corners?

It would be great if somebody can show me some python code to do this, thanks in advance.

```
/* below is my currunt code
# coding:utf8
import cv2
import numpy as np
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
imagePath = sys.argv[1]
img = cv2.imread(imagePath)  

img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img,(3,3),0)  
canny = cv2.Canny(img, 50, 150)

#element2 = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (4, 4))
#dilation = cv2.dilate(canny, element2, iterations = 1)
cv2.imwrite("canny.jpg", dilation)
cv2.waitKey(0)  
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Please edit your question and paste the code there, not in the comments.

Comment: attach the code to your question

Comment: Please add more details/code about your problem and your own efforts this far to solve the problem so that people can help you better. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

I adapted the code [from pyimagesearch](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/09/01/build-kick-ass-mobile-document-scanner-just-5-minutes/) to work in python 3.5 and opencv 3.3

```
import os

import cv2
import imutils
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image

def order_points(pts):
    # initialzie a list of coordinates that will be ordered
    # such that the first entry in the list is the top-left,
    # the second entry is the top-right, the third is the
    # bottom-right, and the fourth is the bottom-left
    rect = np.zeros((4, 2), dtype="float32")

    # the top-left point will have the smallest sum, whereas
    # the bottom-right point will have the largest sum
    s = pts.sum(axis=1)
    rect[0] = pts[np.argmin(s)]
    rect[2] = pts[np.argmax(s)]

    # now, compute the difference between the points, the
    # top-right point will have the smallest difference,
    # whereas the bottom-left will have the largest difference
    diff = np.diff(pts, axis=1)
    rect[1] = pts[np.argmin(diff)]
    rect[3] = pts[np.argmax(diff)]

    # return the ordered coordinates
    return rect


def four_point_transform(image, pts):
    # obtain a consistent order of the points and unpack them
    # individually
    rect = order_points(pts)
    (tl, tr, br, bl) = rect

    # compute the width of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between bottom-right and bottom-left
    # x-coordiates or the top-right and top-left x-coordinates
    widthA = np.sqrt(((br[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((br[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    widthB = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - tl[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - tl[1]) ** 2))
    maxWidth = max(int(widthA), int(widthB))

    # compute the height of the new image, which will be the
    # maximum distance between the top-right and bottom-right
    # y-coordinates or the top-left and bottom-left y-coordinates
    heightA = np.sqrt(((tr[0] - br[0]) ** 2) + ((tr[1] - br[1]) ** 2))
    heightB = np.sqrt(((tl[0] - bl[0]) ** 2) + ((tl[1] - bl[1]) ** 2))
    maxHeight = max(int(heightA), int(heightB))

    # now that we have the dimensions of the new image, construct
    # the set of destination points to obtain a "birds eye view",
    # (i.e. top-down view) of the image, again specifying points
    # in the top-left, top-right, bottom-right, and bottom-left
    # order
    dst = np.array([
        [0, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, 0],
        [maxWidth - 1, maxHeight - 1],
        [0, maxHeight - 1]], dtype="float32")

    # compute the perspective transform matrix and then apply it
    M = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(rect, dst)
    warped = cv2.warpPerspective(image, M, (maxWidth, maxHeight))

    # return the warped image
    return warped

def image_process(image_path):
    # Open image
    image = cv2.imread(image_path)
    ratio = image.shape[0] / 500.0
    orig = image.copy()
    image = imutils.resize(image, height=500)
     # Canny edge detect
    edged = cv2.Canny(image, 75, 200)
     # Find the countours
    img, cnts, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(edged.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
     # Find the contours that are the largest (not sure if applies to this project) and has four components (is a rectangle)
    cnts = sorted(cnts, key=cv2.contourArea, reverse=True)[:5]
    for c in cnts:
        peri = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
        approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.02 * peri, True)
        if len(approx) == 4:
            screenCnt = approx
            break
    warped = four_point_transform(orig, screenCnt.reshape(4, 2) * ratio)
    return warped


def main():
    image_path = None # You're going to need to change this
    image = image_process(image_path)
    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you! The code works perfect on my computer! I have to spend some time to read through the code.

Comment: So this answered your question? If so, could you mark it?

Comment: Click the check mark, just under the up and down arrows. It's to the left and near the top of the post.

Comment: You mean the pentacle under  up and down arrows? I checked it, thanks again for your help.